# Hosting a social web application

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting, vps, rackspace

*Sorry but this question is not directly related to programming, so some of you wont like it, but I really want some advice from you all, so please please allow me to ask..*

I am a Java Web Application Developer. I have an idea for a web application project that I am working on.

I personally believe that this web app has potential to become a widely popular website, (if everything goes right as conceived). It is a *kind of* social web application with users and their content. Currently I am working on it as a developer with two others in the project. The development costs  has been 0(*zero*) uptil now since we are doing in-house development with open source technologies.

But the costs are now going to appear as we'll have to host our application online on the servers. Right now I see this as the major expense as we go live.

Are there any ways by which we can smartly deal with this hurdle ?
We want to minimize the costs as much as possible, or even better, if we can make this  null, perhaps, through some partnership agreement with the hosting solutions provider!?
Your opinions are highly solicited!!

Please enlighten me with your experiences and knowledge... Thank you so much, for your time !

Comment: Since this is ServerFault, `not programming related` is something we don't care about. No worries there. Unfortunately, this question is very, very broad and can't have a canonical answer; all java-apps are different in their impact to operations. It's not a good fit. Once you have some narrower concern, do ask again.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to find a hosting provider that can provide any level of scale who will "partner" with you. You don't have anything they will want except money, so you should save yourself a lot of wasted time and effort and take that idea off the table now.

I almost flagged this question for being too open and vague, but maybe it would be more helpful to tell you why this is so. There are lots of entry-level hosting providers. Far too many to list here. They have varying prices and capabilities. You need to decide what kind of commitment and budget you have. Are you going to manage the operating systems yourself? Do you want application support? You need to understand your answers to these questions before you can move on.

Comment: Have to agree with blueben, this isn't a case of finding someone to "partner" with when you're just starting out, it's simply a matter of a business relationship; finding a hosting company you're comfortable with using.